# How many sets of $n$ items out of $m$ items so that each pair of sets has exactly $x$ items in common?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a general formula for how many subsets of $n$ items out of a $m$ items universe, so that pairwise the cardinality of the intersection of two subsets is  exactly $x$ ?

$ \mathbf A = \{a_1 \ a_2 \ ... \ a_m \} \Rightarrow \vert \mathbf{A} \vert = m\\
\mathbf{B_1},\mathbf{B_2},...\mathbf{B_g} \subseteq \mathbf{A} \\ 
\vert \mathbf{B_1} \vert = \vert \mathbf{B_2} \vert = \ ... \ =\vert\mathbf{B_g}\vert = n \\
\vert \mathbf{B_p} \cap \mathbf{B_q} \vert=x \ \ \forall p,q \ \vert \ p \neq q \\
m,n,x \in \Bbb{N} \ \ \ m \ge n \ge x \\
max \ g(m,n,x) = ? $

Up to now I have the solution for two cases

$x=0 \Rightarrow g(m,n,0) = \lfloor\frac{m}{n}\rfloor \\
x=n \Rightarrow g(m,n,n) = 1 $

The upper limit for any $x$ is clearly the combinations

$ \\ g(m,n,x) \le UL = \binom mn = \frac{m!}{n! (m-n)!} $

Another upper limit that I could find is

$g(m,n,x) \le UL_2 = 1+ \frac{n!} {x! * (n-x)!} * \frac{(m-n)!}{(n-x)! (m-2n+x)!}$

Comment: The question originated on Facebook and was asked by another guy on Quora. Here the relevant answer, which is quite good but maybe not completely satisfactory. https://www.quora.com/Given-a-set-T-with-n-elements-we-look-for-a-maximal-family-A_1-A_k-of-subsets-of-T-such-that-A_i-m-and-A_i-cap-A_j-r-How-can-we-find-k-given-n-m-and-r#bICzD